# How to use JavaScript math.round in an HTML IMG tag?

Tags: javascript

Background: I have a simple web page displaying current weather conditions from a backyard weather station. I am trying to add a UV image on the web site. I'm comfortable with basic HTML, but JavaScript seems like a foreign language to me. I've found threads about using `Math.round`, and calling images in JavaScript, but haven't figured out how to combine the two.

My weather software outputs the UV Index with a one-place decimal point. I want to round to an integer, and then use that integer to place an image relevant to that integer on the web page.

I've figured out how to get `Math.round` to replace the template's UV callout with an integer. The software's template tag for UV is `STAT$UV:CURRENT$`. When I put this in a JavaScript (with text before and after to give the entire image file name) it looks like this:

```
UV_<script type="text/javascript">document.write(Math.round(STAT$UV:CURRENT$));</script>.gif
```

This results in `UV_X.gif` being displayed on my web page, as expected, where X equals the current UV Index. But when I try to wrap this in an IMG tag I can't get the results I'm after.

I think I need to use a variable, but I don't understand variables and the syntax needed to call out the image.

Any suggestions?

**[EDIT]**

I tested the three suggestions in the answers below. None resulted in displaying the image, so I've probably not explained my question well enough.

The weather software runs locally on my computer. It receives a packet of data from the outdoor weather station, processes that data, and displays it on screen. It also populates a locally stored template and then uploads it to my web site via FTP. Other than a couple pre-packages scripts on the server, everything is processed locally. My test page for these suggestions is at avon-weather.com/test.html Take a peek and see if you see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: can you update with the exact html that isn't working (incl img tag)?

Comment: why don't you use a server method to do the rounding?

Comment: I've tried several so far. Sorry, not familiar with this forum format.

    <img src="images/UV/UV_<script type="text/javascript">document.write(Math.round(STAT$UV:CURRENT$));</script>.gif">

Comment: Jan, I don't know what that is. I only know very basic HTML, and don't know how to do server stuff.

Comment: @AvonWeather what server language you are using?

Comment: Best way would be to solve it server side: can you tell us which is the software's template name? I mean the name of the template engine .. so we can understand which language is used server side

Comment: @LucaBorrione seems to me that the templating engine is the weather station itself, in which case it's not going to be very advaced :-( Should have realised sooner.

Comment: That is correct, Jan. The weather software runs locally on my computer. It receives a packet of data from the outdoor weather station, processes that data, and displays it on screen. It also populates a locally stored template and then uploads it to my web site via FTP. Other than a couple pre-packages scripts on the server , everything is processed locally. My test page for these suggestions is at http://www.avon-weather.com/test.html

Comment: Some question-marks got into the scripts while copy-pasting, causing syntax errors. Fix them. They should be white-space.

Comment: I saw that, Jan! I don't see them in my template, but they showed up after it was populated. I just edited the template and will try it again. the template is processed every five minutes, so bear with me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Aha! Kolink and Abdullah's examples worked for me this time. I'm not sure what happened with yours, Jan. Maybe I misinterpreted your suggestion. I'll go with Abdullah's for now, as it avoids document.write as suggested.  

Thanks so much to all three of you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably round the number on the server side since you are using a server framework. Also, try to avoid `document.write` if you can, it can cause some tricky issues if you don't fully understand it (especially if you are mixing server-side and client-side rendering). However, here's an example of how you can do it on the client side:

```
<img id="myImage" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var imgSrc = "UV_" + Math.round(STAT$UV:CURRENT$) + ".gif";
    document.getElementById("myImage").setAttribute('src', imgSrc);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Abdullah, I'm trying these suggestions out now. Takes a couple minuted for the weather software to populate the templates and then FTP to my web site.  I don't know anything about how to do server side stuff. Just very basic HTML.

Comment: I copy/pasted your suggestion, and added the path to my images. It didn't result in an image being posted to the web site. Please see my edit to the original question.

Comment: After editing out a couple hidden characters this worked great! Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

`document.write` shouldn't be used. The modern way would be:

```
<img id="set-me" />
...
<script>
  document.getElementByID("set-me").src = 
    "UV_"+Math.round(STAT$UV:CURRENT$)+".gif";
</script>
```

If you are willing to use jQuery,

```
 <img id="set-me" />
 ...
 <script>
   $("#set-me").attr("src",
     "UV_"+Math.round(STAT$UV:CURRENT$)+".gif");
 </script>
```

Comment: "document.write is deprecated." Really? Says who?

Comment: For starters, `document.write` causes the browser to drop any parsing it may have done asynchronously with the script. It also doesn't work in `xhtml+xml` mode. http://javascript.info/tutorial/document-write

Comment: Thanks Jan, I'm trying these suggestions out now. Takes a couple minuted for the weather software to populate the templates and then FTP to my web site.

Comment: I copy/pasted your suggestion, and added the path to my images. It didn't result in an image being posted to the web site. Please see my edit to the original question.

Comment: @AvonWeather I fixed the mismatched single/double quotes. It should work now as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just shove a `<script>` tag in the middle of an `<img>` tag and expect it to work. It works with PHP because PHP is handled server-side independently of the HTML, but JavaScript is an element in HTML.

Instead, try uding `document.write()` around the entire `<img>` tag, something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write('<img src="UV_'+Math.round(STAT$UV:CURRENT$)+'.gif"/>');
</script>
```

Comment: Please don't recommend `document.write`, even if OP mentions it.

Comment: Thanks Kolink, I figured that one out pretty quickly. I'm trying these suggestions out now. Takes a couple minuted for the weather software to populate the templates and then FTP to my web site.

Comment: I copy/pasted your suggestion, and added the path to my images. It didn't result in an image being posted to the web site. Please see my edit to the original question.

Comment: After editing out a couple hidden characters this worked great! Thanks for your suggestion